# How do I edit a FormCollection value, and then use TryUpdateModel with the edited collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

MVC5 is storing my passwords in plaintext. I don't want to use the default hashing algorithm, as I'm *required* to use `e.Encrypt()` instead. I'm creating a registration function, and I need to know how I can edit values from `FormCollection` before using `TryUpdateModel`.

Here's the code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register([Bind(Include = "User,Pass,Email")] FormCollection form)
    {
        var user = new Users();
        string Hash = e.Encrypt(form["Pass"]); // Gets set.
        if (TryUpdateModel(user, form))
        {
            context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

I've searched high and low, and everything I've found is irrelevant to my needs.

I've tried this:

```
form["Password"] = e.Encrypt(form["Password"])
```

...and that compiles, but when debugging, the value never gets set. `e.Encrypt()` does work as a function, so it's not that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use model binding and a strongly typed model instead of `FormCollection`.

Comment: Could you please convert your comment's suggestion into code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out after some trial and error:

```
    [HttpPost]
    // Remove FormCollection and replace with UserModel.
    public ActionResult Register([Bind(Include= "Username,Password,EmailAddress")] UserModel user)
    {
        if (TryUpdateModel(user))
        {
            // Set password in TryUpdate success.
            user.Password = e.Encrypt(user.Password);; // Set correctly

            context.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Added;
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

However, another issue popped up, `DataValidationError`. The issue is from the `UserModel.cs` class:

```
    [RegularExpression(RegexPassword, ErrorMessage = ErrorPassword)]
```

I had a regular expression which didn't match the hash, so when I tried to update, it was unable to validate. That's a problem for another thread, but I just removed it for now.